# Explain different views on software quality?

Tags: interview

Different views on software quality?
Please explain me in details.

Comment: Voting to Close - Good practice will be if you could ask questions where you need help but those should not be opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Views of Software Quality
David Garvins described software quality from five different perspectives:**

**Transcendental view**
Quality is something that can be recognized but not defined.

**User view**
Quality is fitness for purpose. This view of quality evaluates the product in a task context, how the product meet the user's needs. It can thus be a highly 
personalized view. This view is often measured by reliability, usability.

**Manufactoring view**
Quality is conformance to specification. It focuses on how well the product was constructed, in an effort to avoid the costs associated with rework during development and after delivery. Defect counts and rework costs are two characteristics to measure.

**Product view**
Quality is tied to inherent product characteristics. It assumes that measuring and controlling internal product properties (internal quality indicators) will result in improved external product behavior (quality in use).

**Value-based view**
Quality depends on the amount the customer is willing to pay for it.

Software quality is customer satisfaction. Indeed customer satisfaction should be a result of delivering a quality product, but satisfaction can be influenced by many things and is not the same as quality. Moreover, customers routinely are satisfied by poor quality and not satisfied by high quality.

[Refer This](http://www.ia.hiof.no/~kyvh/se/modules/se/softqua.html)

Comment: @SnehaSingh Welcome